# How can I remove empty client_secret from request body for OAuth 2.0 token requests in Postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-cognito

When attempting to get a new access token using OAuth 2.0 scheme in Postman, it sends an empty `client_secret` and AWS Cognito returns with HTTP 500 (Internal Error).

The authorization code is retrieved successfully using the `/authorize` endpoint, but it's the `/token` that fails.

How can I make Postman remove the client secret? I haven't specified any in the configuration.

[image]